# Как можно поместить два блока div на "дно" другого блока

Tags: css

Проблема в том, что у меня не получается закрепить их внизу. 
Буду рад, если сообщество подскажет. Спасибо!

```css
.div-chat-window {
  border: 5px double #2c3e50;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.div-chat-text-field {
  width: 95%;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.input-text-field {
  width: 100%;
}

.div-button-send-message {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-chat-window">
  <div class="div-chat-text-field">
    <input class="input-text-field" type="text" name="text-chat-field" placeholder="Enter your message... ">
  </div>
  <div class="div-button-send-message">
    <button id="Send">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добавьте разметку

Comment: @E_K, добавил разметку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Что бы разместить элементы в нижней части блока нужно использовать свойство `align-items: flex-end`.
2. Теперь добавим `height: 100px;`  для родительского блока `div-chat-window` вместо `div-chat-text-field`

```css
.div-chat-window {
  height: 100px;
  border: 5px double #2c3e50;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
}

.div-chat-text-field {
  width: 95%;
  bottom: 0;
}

.input-text-field {
  width: 100%;
}

.div-button-send-message {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="div-chat-window">
  <div class="div-chat-text-field">
    <input class="input-text-field" type="text" name="text-chat-field" placeholder="Enter your message... ">
  </div>
  <div class="div-button-send-message">
    <button id="Send">Send</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!